# How to sort folders with images containing from high-res to low-res

Tags: image, sorting, resolution

Hello There,

```
        I have around 40 folders containing images. every folder have images with different resolution.
```

Example  Folder 1 have 3000x2000 res images
         Folder 2 have 1500x1000 res images
         Folder 3 have 1920x1080 res images
                             ..
                   and so on.
         some folder with 1000x800 res images

How to sort them High res image containing folder first and smallest resolution 
containing folder at last.

is there any utility present?

Comment: There's no real concept of sorting folders. How about just naming the folder with the highest resolution images `01-images` and the next highest one `02-images` and so on?

Comment: I cant rename folders because i have more then 100 folders. By the way I got the solution. Xyplorer scripting make it happened.

Answer (score 0):

I cant rename folders because i have more then 100 folders. By the way I got the solution. Xyplorer scripting make it happened.
$secondPicture = gettoken(quicksearch("/types={:Image} /n", , "|"), 2, "|");
    return eval([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvOYw.png)replace(property("#image.dimensions", $secondPicture), "x", "*"));